# Floating floors have soft spots and bubbling - Pulte

Tags: flooring, floor, hardwood-floor, underlayment

https://imgur.com/a/HHlTYmA

I got a new build and it has been a headache. The floors had soft spots and bubbles and I finally got the builders to replace the flooring but it's even worst than before. Checking the videos, I saw that they did not do the underlayment correctly and could be why there are soft spots.

Also, they did not prep the planks beforehand and just left it in the room.

What the builders are saying is that the planks are too cold.. they've been in my room for 3 weeks with the heater on 24/7 so how can that be.

Am I thinking this right, should they re do it all again?

context: floating floors, engineer wood, concrete subfloor

Thank you!

https://imgur.com/a/HHlTYmA

Comment: I have a feeling they did not make sure the floor was flat enough.  Should be able to run a long straight edge along the floor and only see a tiny bit(two/three playing cards) of light between the edge and sub floor.

Comment: I am assuming by soft spots, it is the planks moving/bouncing and not the planks are soft themselves.  This is caused by dips/ridges/waves on the sub floor more than the planks should have.

Comment: What was to be done to the planks to "prep" them?  Seriously curious.  I know about acclimation, but never heard a plank needed prepped.

Comment: This is the before pic, before concrete and the new floor: https://imgur.com/a/0b6ap7r

This is how they put the concrete in: https://imgur.com/a/vYowUhu